# How to find the inner text from xmlnodelist node = doc.getelementbytagname

Tags: c#

```
XmlNodeList node = DOC.GetElementsByTagName("CheckMarkObject");

        foreach (XmlNode nodes in node)
        {
            string name = null;
             name = node.innertext;
        }



        checkmark.Label = node[0].InnerText;   
        checkmark.Name = node[0].InnerText;
        //checkmark.IsChecked = form[0].InnerText;
        CreateControlsUsingObjects(checkmark);
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable names should be other way round

```
   XmlNodeList nodes = DOC.GetElementsByTagName("CheckMarkObject");

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        string name = node.InnerText;
    }
```

### Update

```
   //using System.Data;
   public DataTable getNodesData(XmlNodeList nodes)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        if (nodes.Count <= 0)
            return dt;

        foreach (XmlNode childnode in nodes[0].ChildNodes)
            dt.Columns.Add(childnode.Name);

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (XmlNode childnode in node.ChildNodes)
                dr[childnode.Name] = childnode.InnerText;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;
    }

    XmlNodeList nodes = DOC.GetElementsByTagName("CheckMarkObject");
    DataTable dt = getNodesData(nodes); 

    //Bind your dt to GridView, DataList, Repeater etc
```

or

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    print(row["Name"]);
    print(row["IsChecked"]);
    print(row["Label"]);
}
```

Comment: bro ! it give null exception at "checkmark.label". 
actually i trying to create layout at runtime from XML.

Comment: means that nodes is empty. what are you trying to achieve - set the name?

Comment: i am try'n to get node. and put it in a variable. and get name and label from XML. that is: <CheckMarkObject><Name>subscribeCheckmark</Name><Label>Subscribe</Label><IsChecked>1</IsChecked></CheckMarkObject>
and give layout of this xml at runtime